# Overloading indexOf() for a custom created ArrayList of objects using one element of object

Tags: java, arraylist, overloading, indexof

I'm attempting to create a to-do list program and I'm having some trouble finding a way to delete elements by searching for a specific item.

I'm attempting to implement `indexOf()` that'll return the index of an element that contains the item searched within an ArrayList of Items but instead it only returns -1, not found.

I've overloaded the function in my ToDo class and overloaded the equals(Object o) and hashCode() in my Item class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class ToDo {

    ArrayList<Item> TodoList = new ArrayList<>();


    static String [] itemData = new String[100];       //to index items added to list
    //itemData = new String[100];
    static int size=0;

    public void addItem(String item, String category, int priority)
    {
        TodoList.add(new Item(item,category,priority));
        itemData[size] = item;  //for indexing
        size++;
    }

    //remove item at specified index spot
    private void removeItem(int i )
    {

        TodoList.remove(i);

    }

    public void getList()
    {
        for (Item item : TodoList)
        {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }
    }

    public int getIndex(String item)
    {
        return (TodoList.indexOf(item));

    }

    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (itemData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(itemData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }




    public void print() {
        System.out.println("To-do List: ");
        System.out.println("-----------");
        getList();
        if (TodoList == null) {
            System.out.println("You're all done for today!");
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ToDo todo = new ToDo();


        todo.addItem("Get pickles", "Shopping", 2);
        todo.addItem("Read book", "School", 3);
        todo.addItem("Send letter", "Other", 1);
        todo.addItem("Buy planner", "School", 4);
        todo.addItem("Get potatoes", "Shopping", 3);
        todo.print();

        System.out.println("------------");
        //todo.removeItem("Read book","School","3");
        //todo.removeItem(1);

        System.out.println("INDEX OF READ BOOK (1) :" + todo.getIndex("ReadBook"));

        //todo.removeItem(todo.getIndex("ReadBook"));
        //todo.print();

        System.out.println("SIZE: " + size);

    }

}
```

```
public class Item {


    public int i;
    private String item;
    private String category;
    private int priority;



    //default constructor to initialize
    public Item(String item, String category, int priority){
        this.item = item;
        this.category = category;
        this.priority = priority;
    }



    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    //used in order to overload indexOf() method
    //*****************************************************
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Item) {
            //item comparison
            Item mo = (Item)o;
            return mo.item.equals(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return java.util.Objects.hashCode(item);
    }

    // *****************************************************

    public String translatePriority()
    {
        if (priority == 1)
            return "low";
        else if (priority == 2)
            return "medium";
        else if (priority == 3)
            return "high";
        else if (priority == 4)
            return "urgent";
        else
            return "invalid priority";

    }



    public String toString() {
        return  "Category : " + category + " || Priority Level: " + translatePriority() + "\nTask : " + item + "\n";
    }





}
```

Comment: Don't use a separate array for your index. Just scan through the ArrayList of Items. And make the type of the parameter to indexOf the actual type you want (String), not Object. Otherwise your class is difficult to use, as it isn't clear what needs to be passed to that method.

Comment: And you're not overloading indexOf -- that would only be the case if you were extending a class or implementing an interface which already defined it.

Comment: You are passing a string to `TodoList.indexOf(item)` but `Item.equals()` only handles `Item`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All instances of **Item** are contained within the **ToDoList** ArrayList. Obviously, anything you need to access can be done through this list of **Item** objects. If your search is to be specific towards the **Item#item** instance variable then you would need to iterate through the **ToDoList** collection and compare the *search criteria* (ReadBooks) with what may be contained within any one instance of **Item#item**. If a match is detected then the iteration process is halted and the current index of that iteration is returned. This then means that changes are required for your **getIndex()** method:

```
public int getIndex(String item) {
    int index = -1;
    String itemString = item.replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < TodoList.size(); i++) {
        String listItem = TodoList.get(i).getItem().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase();
        // I think it's better to use the String#contains() method
        // instead of the String#indexOf() method.
        if (listItem.contains(itemString)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

You may notice that white-spaces are removed from any supplied search criteria and the string is reduced to all lower letter case. The same is done with every instance of **Item#item** string acquired through iteration. This is done for those cases where the search criteria is supplied as `"ReadBook"` even though the item instance was clearly filled with `"Read book"`. The code above should find the relationship. You will also notice that the **String#contains()** method is used instead of the **String#indexOf()** method. I believe this is better suited for this particular situation.

If you would prefer your search to be more global across all Item instance member variables then you would be better off to compare the search criteria against an Item instance of toString(), for example:

```
String listItem = TodoList.get(i).toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase();
```

It would be a good idea however to change the **Item#toString()** returnable string format to perhaps something a little less detailed like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder("").append(category).append(", ")
            .append(translatePriority()).append(", ").append(item)
            .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of issues with you code:
You are calling indexOf() of ArrayList class, you need to change to this to call your own method

```
   public int getIndex(String item)
    {
        return (indexOf(item));

    }
```

and this line of code will not match any of the sample item, therefore it would return -1

```
todo.getIndex("ReadBook")
```

perhaps, you meant to write?

```
todo.getIndex("Read book")
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few issues to point out here.

You have declared `TodoList` to be `ArrayList<Item>`.

So your code:

```
public int getIndex(String item) {
    return (TodoList.indexOf(item));
}
```

Is always going to return -1. The list contains `Item`s not strings.

You have declared an array to hold item names 'for indexing'. This doesn't make a lot of sense. It'll take just as long to iterate through the array looking for a name as it would be looking through the original list. And you will have the problem of keeping the indices in sync.

A better option is to just store the items in a list and search for an item with the given name:

```
IntStream.range(0, ToDoList.size())
    .filter(i -> ToDoList.get(i).getItem().equals(item))
    .findAny().orElse(-1);
```